# CakePHP 2.0 adds a controller's name to image path specified in CSS

Tags: css, cakephp-2.0

I've got this problem. In my css code, I have the following:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .footer {
    padding: 15px;      
    border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    background: url('/img/layout/content/box/actions-bg.png') #f0f1f4 repeat-x;
}
```

I get this error:

> Error 404 Not found http://backoffice.example.com/products/img/layout/content/box/actions-bg.png

Somehow cakePHP adds the name of my controller "products" to the path. So, the error is because cakePHP does not find a method named 'img'

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your question.  In the future, you can prefix error messages with a ">" to have them formatted easily and correctly.

Comment: Cake will not touch your CSS. What is the path in the "view source" ?